# Relative speed of objects

Tags: inertial-frames, relative-motion

This question has been bugging me for a while now. I am not sure this is the correct forum to ask, please close if it is not the right forum.

Lets say a bus is traveling at $60\: \mathrm{km/h}$ and there is a mosquito flying inside the bus. Since the mosquito's speed is considerably less than that of the bus why it wouldn't end up hitting the back side of the bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was no air in the bus you'd be right (but then what would the mosquito be flying in?).  When the bus travels, it pushes the air inside of the bus too so the air moves at the same speed as the bus.  The mosquito is flying in this air so it's getting pushed by the air and it moves relative to the bus.

This is just like when you're sitting in a car and it starts to accelerate.  The seat behind and under you pushes you so you move at the same speed as the car.